# Failure to end Flask application

Tags: python, flask, internal-server-error

I have a flask application as follows:

```
socketio2.run(app2, host="0.0.0.0", port=4998)
```

I created a method to end it as follows:

```
def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

@app2.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    print " shutdown"
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

I get the following error

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

My target is to end this Flask app and run a Python script afterwards. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you imported the request module? i.e.: `from flask import request`

Comment: Yes I have imported it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running the server as a socketio server, the default shutdown server code will not work. However, socketio does provide a wrapper to stop and when you use it, the default behaviour should stop the server.  [https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/flask_socketio/**init**.py#L510](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/flask_socketio/__init__.py#L510)

So if you modify your code to something like this -

```
def shutdown_server():
    socketio2.stop()
```

Then it should do the job